JsonRpcProvider not working
I have been trying to use the Uniswap v3 sdk in my frontend. For this,I use ethers version "5.7.2" .In the tutorial contract, this is the code to connect an RPC endpoint. The tutorial code also uses ethers version "5.7.2".
import { ethers, providers } from 'ethers'
import { CurrentConfig } from '../config'

// Provider Functions

export function getProvider(): providers.Provider {
  return new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(CurrentConfig.rpc.mainnet)
}


And this is my implementation of the jsonRpcProvider function
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import CurrentConfig from "../../CurrentConfig";

export function getProvider() {
  let x = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(CurrentConfig.rpc.mainnet);
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}

If I do this,I'm able to connect to the network but not able to call any smart contract functions with their instances.(The instance gets returned as Proxy(Contract).The location is from "ethers" package and not from "@ethersproject" package.

The instance gets returned as Proxy(Contract) or Promise(Contract)?

It is returned as Proxy(Contract) .And ,I tried printing the jsonRpcProvider's return value. The one printed in the tutorial program is different from my my program!

Can you share the link of the tutorial that you're following?

No,I use the code from the docs. Here is the repo link https://github.com/Uniswap/examples/tree/main/v3-sdk/quoting . But this is working fine,the problem is with my code
